# Ionic Missing Default Resources

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello i am working on ionic application. with executing this command `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`. it does generate the unasigned apk file. but it also show error.

**Error :**
this error is reference to config.xml file splash screen src path.

> \platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png:
>   Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-mdpi has no declaration
>   in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this
>   can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration
>   that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
>
> Explanation for issues of type "MissingDefaultResource":  If a
>   resource is only defined in folders with qualifiers like -land or -en,
>   and there is no default declaration in the base folder (layout or
>   values  etc), then the app will crash if that resource is accessed on
>   a device  where the device is in a configuration missing the given
>   qualifier.

**Reference**
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/issues/214

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add the following and it works

```
<splash density="ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
<splash density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
```

**Reference** [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/drawable-error-apk-production/163594/4)

Answer (score 0):

While it's better to address the cause where applicable, you *can* also ignore these errors by adding the following to your **build.gradle** file under the android section

```
 lintOptions { disable 'MissingDefaultResource' }
```

This will prevent lint from raising an error during the build.